# Piping PIDs into kill doesn't work

Tags: pipe, kill

I'm fighting a bug in IntelliJ where nailgun instances screw up when SNAPSHOT dependencies are updated. I want to **automate killing all processes that contain nailgun in their name**.

So far I can get all relevant PIDs like so:

```
ps -x -o pid,cmd | grep nailgun | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

This gives me for example:

```
26759
27852
28817
29963
31234
31577
```

I can go and run `kill` for each of them manually, like `kill 26759` etc. But piping doesn't work:

```
ps -x -o pid,cmd | grep nailgun | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | kill
```

This just prints

> kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

**How do I pipe the list of PIDs to kill?**

Answer (score 3):

Putting the PIDs onto one line with `xargs` works:

```
ps -x -o pid,cmd | grep nailgun | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs kill
```

The only annoyance is that this prints `kill: (xyz): No such process` for the `grep` instance which shows up in the `ps` list as well.

Another alternative:

```
pgrep -f nailgun | xargs kill
```

Comment: If you’re going to use `pgrep`, you might as well use `pkill`.

Comment: It works better because kill doesn't read stdin; it wants the pids as args, which xargs does.

Comment: See also [`whereis`, pipeline and `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364079/86440).

Comment: You could also just add another grep to filter our 'grep' in the results e..g `ps -x -o pid,cmd | grep nailgun | grep -v 'grep' | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs kill`.  FYI for me I had to `cut -f 2 -d ' '` as well.