# Why isn't `which ls | file` working?

Tags: files, ls, which

I would like to use the result of `which ls` and see the file type using `file`. However, when I type in `which ls | file` it doesn't work. When I try to do `file < which ls`, that doesn't work either.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `type -a ls` instead. Which is not reliable to use for what you wanr

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Thank you for trying to answer, but I was looking for the result of `file /usr/bin/ls`... Except, I would like to to check for `which` at the same time, and then use the result with `file`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [whereis, pipline and ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364079/whereis-pipline-and-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because `file` takes the file to examine as commandline parameter (see `man file`).

You are piping the output of `which` to the `stdin` of the process executing `ls`.

What you *should* do is something like `file "$(which ls)"`.

Comment: Aaaah... Perfect!

Comment: But then, why is it that I am able to do something like `man ls | head`... Although, `head` would also be expecting command line arguments ?

Comment: From `man head`:  `With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.`. This means, that `head` takes *stdin* if no FILE is given.

Comment: Aaaah! That makes sense, thank you so much!!